# Checkbox disable enable vis versa

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am trying to achieve a simple task yet it doesnt seem to work maybe I should try a diff approach.

If one box checked then the other is unchecked vis versa

this doesnt work for whatever reason

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="boxone">checkbox one<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" id="boxTwo">CheckBox  two <br>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#boxone").click(function(){
    if ($(this).prop("checked"))
    {
        $("#boxTwo").prop("checked",false);
    }
});

$("#boxTwo").click(function(){
    if ($(this).prop("checked"))
    {
        $("#boxone").prop("checked",false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't this what radio boxes are for?

Comment: @Barmar Unless the mutual-exclusivity is optional...

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/JXL25/ Did you remember to put it in the document ready handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try just this

```
$("#boxone").click(function(){ 
        $("#boxTwo").prop("checked",false);   
});

$("#boxTwo").click(function(){
        $("#boxone").prop("checked",false);
});
```

and try to use different names

Comment: doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: @user2859027 Did you remember to put it in the document ready handler?

Comment: typo name in function did not help, now .